# Changing camera location for one frame changes it for everything

Tags: camera, transforms

I want to create a short 'scene-inspection' video, where the camera should move in a pre-determined trajectory around a scene (x,y,z, and Euler angles).  To test on a couple of frames initially, for frame 1 I set y- value to -10ft, and for frame 2 to -10.5ft ( ie I am only changing the y direction values).
But I observe that as soon as I set camera location for frame 2, it also changes the value for frame 1 (to -10.5 ft).
The location values arent locked and the camera is always selected as the active object for that frame.
Why is that happening? Pls suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add keyframes to set the location at different points in the animation - otherwise Blender is not aware of how you want the object to move and assumes you are just moving it to its new 'static' location.

You should set a keyframe at the start of the motion - this can be achieved by simply hitting <kbd>I</kbd> and selecting 'Location' (or whatever property you are keyframing) while in the 3D Viewport. Then move to the end frame and move the camera and, again, add a keyframe using the same process. Your camera should now move between those keyframes when you play the animation or move through the timeline.

Comment: Worked! Thks a lot